# Bring back Windows 7 Photo Viewer in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, images, photos

In Windows 8, it seems the old [Windows 7 Photo Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Viewer) has been replaced by the `Photos` app, or at least I can't find it - the wikipedia page states it is included in Windows 8...

The Photos app doesn't seem to have functionality to navigate through images in the current folder (Previous/Next) like `Windows Photo Viewer` did. So when I want to navigate photos in some folder that's not part of my `Pictures Library` I need to open and close them one after the other - a pain.

Is it possible to access or install `Windows Photo Viewer` on Windows 8? Or am I missing something in the `Photos` app that provides this functionality?

I'm sure there are tons of third-party desktop apps that can browse photos, but I enjoyed the Windows 7 one as it was. Or is there a third-party metro app in the store that does this job well in full screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is Windows Photo Viewer of Windows 7 in Windows 8. Just right click on the image you don't want to open with Photo Viewer and then choose `open with` option you will see the Windows Photo Viewer there.

[image]

You can set it default by choosing the option `Choose Default Program` and select the **Windows Photo Viewer** and you will able to open the images in the *Windows Photo Viewer* by default for that format of images. For other formats which are not opening by default in the *Windows Photo Viewer* you can follow the same method for them to open by default in photo viewer.

Comment: Doh.. I installed paint.net and the prompt "There are new apps that can open this type of file" afterwards didn't show it as an option, and I couldn't find it by searching in Apps/Start Menu either, so I had the impression it wasn't there at all. Thanks!

Comment: There is not a lot changes in the Windows 8 regarding the apps they are still providing the old apps of Windows 7 for Windows 8, just they have change some performance issue and some new programs to make it user friendly. Let's see how much user like it over Windows 7.

Comment: If the Photos app could browse Next/Previous in the current folder like Photo Viewer that'd be pretty neat and a worthy Metro app IMO.

Comment: We can't vote for the features to MS :P

Comment: @mtone Photos can go Next/Previous in the current folder if the picture is a part of the Pictures Library

Comment: @PratyushNalam that is a very limited utilization of the Photo viewer :P

Comment: yeah photos app is quite crap at the moment. i use photo gallery

Comment: "We can't vote for the features to MS" - There's http://connect.microsoft.com, but who knows if they even listen?

Comment: @Karan yeah! I don't think they care :P

Comment: That's why we are all here, trying to fix their mistakes and missing features! :D

Comment: @Karan lol! They don't realize that what people do with their OS according to their need.